# Recursively render objects in a nested dictionary to json

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary

How can you iterate through nested dictionaries converting them to json (or any other type of function) as you go, regardless of the length of the dictionaries where the last object in the recursion is a list.

My original Dictionary:

```
dictionary = {
    <obj1> : {
        <obj2>: {
            <obj3>: {
                [<obj4>, <obj5>, <obj6>],
            },
        <obj7>: {
            <obj8>: {
                [<obj9>, <obj10>, <obj11>],
            },
     <obj12> : {
         <obj13>: {
             <obj14>: {
                 [<obj15>, <obj16>, <obj17>],
             },
     }
```

Comment: `import json; json.dumps(dictionary)`?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to implement a type switch and a set of recursive functions:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "MyDict(%s)" % super(MyDict, self).__repr__()

class MyList(list):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "MyList(%s)" % super(MyList, self).__repr__()


def copy_dict(val):
    res = MyDict()
    for k, v in val.items():
        res[k] = copy_value(v)
    return res


def copy_list(val):
    res = MyList()
    for item in val:
        res.append(copy_value(item))
    return res


def copy_default(val):
    return val


COPYFN = {
    dict: copy_dict,
    list: copy_list,
}

def copy_value(v):
    copy_fn = COPYFN.get(type(v), copy_default)
    #print("COPYVAL:", copy_fn, type(v), v)
    return copy_fn(v)



d = dict(hello=dict(beautiful=['world']))

print(copy_value(d))
```

i.e. so copy_value figures out which copy function to call based on the type of it's argument.

If this is just to product json, then use the json module -- don't attempt to write your own json serializer!